# Outlook Contact Scraper

Tags: outlook

I am trying to find a tool or add-in that lets me scrape contact details from Outlook.

More specifically, where I can scrape emails I have received (and the signatures in those emails) to automatically fill out the user's contact details.

I have found a lot of tools that allow me to scrape the name and email, but I also need additional fields, such as their position, postal address and contact number.

I mainly want this as I have a lot of contacts email me from our partners, and I do not always have the time (or remember) to save their contacts with additional details. I often have to go back and search for it, which can be quite time consumptive, even when I can find the details I am looking for.